# Why Q-matrix often set to $C^TC$ in Algebraic Riccati Equations?

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, control-theory, optimal-control, linear-control

I wonder why many books say that the Q-matrix in the Algebraic Riccati Equations:

$$A^T X + X A - X B R^{-1} B^T X + Q = 0 $$
or

$$X = A^T X A -(A^T X B)(R + B^T X B)^{-1}(B^T X A) + Q$$

Is often set to $Q = C^TC$ when finding the steady state kalman gain matrix $K$ in the kalman filter state update:

$$\hat x(k+1) = \hat x(k) + K(y(k) - C\hat x(k))$$

Or finding the optimal control law:

$$u = r - Lx(k+1)$$

Why $Q = C^TC$? I think that is great that it can be at least one answer for the $Q$ matrix instead of saying that the $Q$ matrix should be greater than $0$. But what results will I get if I always say that $Q=C^TC$ ?

Comment: Is your question about ARE regarding LQR or Kalman filter? Because the ARE seem to be for LQR and I have only seen $Q=C^\top C$ being used for LQR, but you mention that it is used for a Kalman filter.

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen What would happen if we used $Q =C^TC$ for a kalman filter?

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen Yes. my question is about Kalman Filter, and also LQR.

Comment: $Q=C^\top C$ for a Kalman filter would imply that the assumed model for the process noise lies in the span of $C^\top$. A more common choice would be $Q=B\,B^\top$ which would mean that the process noise enters at the same place as the normal inputs to the system. It can be noted that $Q=B\,B^\top$ for the Kalman filter is the dual equivalent of $Q=C^\top C$ for LQR.

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen Thank you. You answer the question :) But don't the noise affect the output measurement?

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen Hmm...I notice that $Q= C^TC$ and $Q=BB^T$ won't work for estimated $C$ and $B$.

Comment: I don't think $Q = C^T C$ is often used in practise though. In books it might be just for convenience because with that $Q$ all outputs contribute to the cost function which is reasonable to assume.

Comment: @SampleTime So I have to choose $Q$ as it find it's best purpose? Like a tuning parameter? Else I just can set it to $Q =I$ if I don't know what to select?

Comment: @DanielMårtensson I have added an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The choice $Q = C^T C$ basically puts cost on the system output. Since often, the output of the system is what we want to control, this is a simple choice that can be used as a first try.

In practise, however, the states (respectively the outputs) can be on very different scales - therefore, it might not make much sense to weight the outputs like that.

What will work best depends on your objectives, but there are different tuning rules to choose the $Q$ matrix. Look for example at [this](https://www.cds.caltech.edu/~murray/courses/cds110/wi06/lqr.pdf) lecture note by R. M. Murray, pages 2 and 3. The tuning rule there is based on selecting a diagonal $Q$

$$
Q = \text{diag}(\begin{bmatrix} q_{1} & q_{2} & \dots & q_{n} \end{bmatrix})
$$

Then you choose, based on your system knowledge, values that are "just well enough" for your purpose. For example (adapted from the above linked reference): say $x_1$ is a position error and $x_2$ an angular position error. Based on your system knowledge, you decide

$$
\begin{align}
1 \text{ cm position error is "still OK"} &\Rightarrow q_1 = \Big( \frac{1}{100} \Big)^2 \newline 
\frac{1}{60} \text{ rad angular error is "still OK"} &\Rightarrow q_2 = 60^2
\end{align}
$$

So, you would then choose your $Q$ matrix as

$$
Q = \text{diag}(\begin{bmatrix} q_{1} & q_{2} \end{bmatrix}) = \begin{bmatrix}
q_1 & 0 \newline
0 & q_2
\end{bmatrix}  = \begin{bmatrix}
0.0001 & 0 \newline
0 & 3600
\end{bmatrix}
$$

As you can see, the scale of these two parameters is very different, so $Q = C^T C$ might be a poor choice here, depending on how both $x_1$ and $x_2$ are measured.